# C - realloc() function - proof it corrupts data

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation, realloc

Look what I found with this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *string;

int main(){    

string = (char *) malloc(50*sizeof(char));
strcpy(string, "initi1l wording cont2ining forty-nine ch3r4cters.");
printf("BEFORE: %s\n", string);
string = (char *) realloc(string, 24*sizeof(char));
printf("AFTER: %s\n", string);

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

The outpout is:

```
BEFORE: initi1l wording cont2ining forty-nine ch3r4cters.
AFTER: initi1l wording cont2inia
```

Notice it 'a' at the end of the string! I have no idea where this comes from, maybe somewhere in the heap. It is not from the original data block. Initially I was using realloc() with arrays of structures and it was obviously corrupting the data in more significant ways.

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Well I might ask one later about how I can work around my problem, see my response to aix's response.

Comment: Well, perhaps there's no question, but the answer is obvious: realloc is not broken.

Answer (score 10):

**C strings require a `NUL` terminator.** You're implicitly expecting `realloc()` to somehow figure out that the memory contains a C string, and replace its last character with `NUL`. It doesn't do this; you have to do it yourself:

```
string = (char *) realloc(string, 24*sizeof(char));
string[23] = 0;   // <========= THE FIX
printf("AFTER: %s\n", string);
```

In other words, it's a bug in your code.

Comment: Yes, true. Thank you for pointing that out, but... When I was shrinking an array of structures to a smaller block I was expecting the last elements to come of the end (and did not have to supply a NULL terminating character). WHat happened was total corruption.

Answer (score 5):

It does not! In C "String" is a set of character **delimited with \0**. In this case you try to print "string", therefore you get your original 24 characters and some tail until random \0 is found in memory

Comment: Ok guys. Thanks. I'll come back when I can prove how realloc is appending random data to my array of structures. (I agree I forgot the NULL in the string example).

Comment: If you use realloc to increase the size, the part behind the old contents contains indeterminate bytes, as specified by the standard. If you use it to shrink the size, the memory behind the new size is just any random memory location for your program, it could contain anything, accessing it is invalid. What actually happens (in this case, other implementations may behave differently) is that realloc overwrites the first few bytes to mark it as free memory.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C are null terminated. I am surprised that the program did not crash.

Comment: Why should it? After the allocated block there may be, for instance, size of the next block, which, if it's short has zero high byte ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's character 25 and you have no 0-termination in the first 24.